# Cancelling async without losing data

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have this while loop:

```
tasks = [self.frontend_wrap(),
                         self.server_wrap()]
completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
for i in pending:
       i.cancel()
for done in completed:
    do staff
```

In other words, I'm waiting for when one the tasks will be completed, and start handling it. The previous one I cancel, due to error "Task already awaited", and I can't reuse it anymore. The problem is, then I cancel my task, I'm loosing data. It happens when tasks are finished "on the same time". So how can I save all data?

Comment: I solved it in another way. I moved `do staff` to `frontend_wrap` and `server_wrap` and create while loop there

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cancelling tasks, use an `asyncio.Event` to allow them to exit on their own:

```
import asyncio

import random

done = asyncio.Event()


async def foo():
    while not done.is_set():
        print("foo")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.4))
        if random.randint(1, 15) == 1:
            break

    print("foo done")
    done.set()


async def bar():
    while not done.is_set():
        print("bar")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.4))
        if random.randint(1, 15) == 1:
            break

    print("bar done")
    done.set()


async def main():
    await asyncio.wait([foo(), bar()])
    # do stuff


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: this is not helpfull at all. `foo` and `bar` blocking each other

Comment: They are not blocking each other. Did you try running this code?

Comment: Because `await` in `foot` is almost blocking in my case. So I seldom check `while not done.is_set():`